# Dynamically getting values of objectliteral without knowing key value names

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, object

I have an object like this

```
obj{quest1:{header1:1},
quest2:{header2:2},
quest3:{header3:3}
}
```

How do i access poperty names... via **Quest1,quest2, quest3**
How do i access inner property names... via **header1,header2,header3**
and
values.. which are **1,2, 3** dynamically in a loop

Answer (score 0):

For a pure JS solution, you can use the for loop:

```
for(var k in obj) {
  for (var k2 in obj[k]) {
    console.log('Property : ' + k + ', Inner ' + k2 + ', Value ' + obj[k][k2]);
  } 
}
```

Prints

```
Property quest1, Inner header1, Value 1
Property quest2, Inner header2, Value 2
Property quest3, Inner header3, Value 3
```

Comment: i want to print all property names, keys and values

Comment: k and k2 hold the key name information for the value

Comment: cant we do it in native JS